# How to select data from one table and insert it into another table with a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select data from one table and insert that Data into another table with
a new column.

For example select the tvseries winner data from the series table and then insert that data into the temp table with the new column called `isselected`.

[image]

`IsSelected` is a new column. It's not in the `tvseries` table

```
 Winner | ISSelected
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking for. What is the column `ISSelected` supposed to mean in said new table (because if everything in that table is marked as `isselected` then it's a redundant column)? And what is your overall goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query should work for you if you already have a temp table.

```
INSERT INTO [TEMP_TABLE_NAME](Winner ,IsSelected)
SELECT Winner ,1
FROM [tvseries]
```

If you want to create a #temp table dynamically using select you can use like following.

```
SELECT Winner ,1 AS IsSelected INTO #Temp
FROM tvseries
```

If you want to explicitly create table and insert the values, you can do like following.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp( Winner VARCHAR(100), IsSelected BIT)
SELECT Winner ,1
FROM [tvseries]
```

Comment: But IsSelected  is a new column. It's not in the tvseries table.

Comment: What is the source of the column, from where it is coming?